# What is the advantage of introsort over quicksort+reshuffle if depth of recursion exceed threshold?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm curious to know why quicksorting algorithms usually divert to heapsort if a pathological case is suspected. Would simply reshuffling non-deterministically the values using a O(n) shuffle and applying quicksort again to the new permutation be a valid alternative to divertion to heapsort?

Comment: What would you do if after shuffling, it still face the pathological case?

Comment: buy lottery tickets. It's a 1 in trillions occurrence.

Comment: Have you considered whether Heapsort may be faster than Shuffle + Quicksort? Heapsort has better worst-case asymptotic behavior and equivalent (up to constants) average-case asymptotic behavior. Shuffling is `O(n)` but may not play nicely with cache for arrays large enough to make performance of sorting relevant.

Comment: That's a great question. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm lead to believe that the standard implementation of quicksort in most libraries already includes a in-place pre-shuffle since without a it (or random pivot selection which amounts to the same), an already ordered array of inputs or a reverse ordered array will be a pathological case for quicksort.

Comment: I've done some testing on my end on the issue and shuffle+quicksort+divertion-to-insertion sort seems to have a better runtime than quicksort+divertion-to-insertion sort when sorting randomly generated inputs by as much as 20%. Shuffling seems to be quite cheap.

Comment: In the case of Microsoft's implementation of std::sort, the code tracks and passes a tree depth level during the quicksort and only switches to heapsort on the parts of the tree that exceed some predefined maximum. If you have the space to use merge sort instead, it's not much slower than quicksort for average cases, and it's faster for the pathological cases. On a processor with 16 registers (most of them used as pointers), like X86 in 64 bit mode, a 4 way merge sort is as fast or faster than quicksort, but I'm not aware of standard libraries that implement it.